# Is there are similar conjecture like this??

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

Talking with my friend, my friend suggest impressive conjecture that

> For $i\in\mathbb{N}$, there are always exist natural number $r$ that satisfies
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{i} \frac{1}{n^r}=\frac{p}{q} , \gcd(p,q)=1$$ and $p+q$ is a prime number.

For example, $$\sum_{n=1}^{2} \frac{1}{n}=\frac{3}{2}$$ and $3+2=5$. And  $i=3$,  $$\sum_{n=1}^{3} \frac{1}{n^4}=\frac{1393}{1296}$$ and $1393+1296=2689$.

$$\sum_{n=1}^{4} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{205}{144}$$ and $205+144=349$ which is 70th prime number.

In $i=5$
 $$\sum_{n=1}^{5} \frac{1}{n^3}=\frac{256103}{216000}$$ and $256103+216000=472103$.

Also  $$\sum_{n=1}^{6} \frac{1}{n^3}=\frac{28567}{24000}$$ and $24000+28567=52567$.

There are similer like this? If not, What about your think, is it true? Or false....

I would glad you guys to think about this thing and share opinions for me and my friend's curiosity.

---

**Note**: ID:metamorphy suggest that 
the sequence of the smallest values of $r$ begins with $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 34, 1, 1, 5, \ldots$. (There are full comment in bellow with more comments.)

Comment: I think you must mean "For every positive integer $i$".

Comment: @TonyK yes,i'll fix it

Comment: @TonyK Thanks,I fix my typo

Comment: You give examples for $i=2,4,6$ and $r=1,2,3$. You don't give examples for $i=3,5$. So is the question "For every $i$ there is and $r$..." or "For every $r$ there is and $i$..."? Your question as written seems to ask the first, but the examples seem to address the second.

Comment: @KeithBackman I add example $i=3,5$

Comment: Funny. The sequence of the smallest values of $r$ begins with $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 34, 1, 1, 5, \ldots$ (here $r_{13} = 34$). I couldn't find $r_{17}$...

Comment: @metamorphy Oh thanks~~and it is impressive.is there any serise about it?

Comment: I don't know. If $r_{17}$ exists at all, then it is $> 1000$ (my computer was running a simple PARI program for $\approx 5$ minutes to get this).

Comment: @metamorphy thank you for your help.I update your discovery in my question. If you mind,I'll delet it.

Comment: Feel free. I would also append the question on $r_{17}$. The PARI "program" is $\texttt{foo(n)={for(r=1,+oo,s=sum(k=1,n,k^(-r));if(isprime(numerator(s)+denominator(s)),return(r)))}}$

Comment: Posted this question on a forum I attended often some time ago... can't resist to report the results kindly found there: $r_{17} > 9230, r_{21} > 8420, r_{34} > 4353$ (with non-existence possible), $r_{41}=121$ (proven, the first example I didn't mention there).

Answer (score 3):

It's likely to be very difficult to prove (or disprove) but I would guess it was true. Here is a heuristic for why I think this.

It's easy to see that the denominator of $\sum_{n=1}^i\frac1{n^r}$ is at most $i!^r$, and the numerator is less than twice that for $r>1$. So we have a bound on the size of $p+q$ of order $k^r$. The prime number theorem suggests that, roughly, a $\frac1{\log(k^r)}=\frac{1}{r\log k}$ proportion of numbers about that size are prime. So if, instead of using your actual numbers, you just picked random numbers of about the right size, the chance of never hitting a prime would be $\prod_{r=2}^{\infty}\big(1-\frac{1}{r\log k}\big)=0$ (this equality follows from the divergence of the harmonic series).

Of course, your numbers aren't random and aren't independent of each other, but in the absence of a good reason why your process is less likely to eventually produce a prime, I suspect it will.